# Static methods in interfaces not working, how to get specific enum value out of several enums?

Tags: java, enums, interface, static

I have several enums that can be found by an int. This is done by a static method on the enum. For example:

```
enum Foo {
 A, B, C, D, ... ;
  public static Foo fromInt(int i) {
  switch(i) {
   case 15: return A;
   case 42: return B;
   ...
 }
}
enum Bar {
 BLA, BOO, BEE, ... ;
  public static Bar fromInt(int i) {
  switch(i) {
   case 78: return BLA;
   case 22: return BOO;
   ...
 }
}
...
```

Now in some code I have a generic type `T` that is guaranteed to be one of these enums and I have an integer `i`. How can I call the `fromInt` method and get the instance of the enum by value `i`?

I have tried creating an interface with a static method `fromInt` and let the enums implement it, but static methods do not work in interfaces.

I can not use Java 8.

Comment: What about reflection?

Comment: So you have somewhere a `Class<T>` variable, right? Could you provide your code with this generic type?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the sets of `int` values in `Foo` and `Bar` are disjoint?

Comment: @MarkBuikema I am trying to understand the motivation behind this design. Why do your classes need to work with "generic" enum constants?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer **you can't**

Long answer you can either pass `Class` of that enum to your method and invoke `fromInt` by reflection or create factory interface and implent it for each your enum then pass right instance to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Extending [@talex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39208513/1225328):

Reflection:

```java
public class YourEnumFactory {

  public static <T extends Enum<T>> T get(Class<T> type,int i) {
    try {
      return (T) type.getDeclaredMethod("fromInt", int.class).invoke(null, i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find instance of '" + type + "' given '" + i + "'", e);
    }
  }

}
```

Factories:

```java
public class YourEnumFactory {

  private interface Factory<T> {
    T fromInt(int i);
  }

  private static final Map<Class<?>, Factory<?>> FACTORIES;
  static {
    Map<Class<?>, Factory<?>> factories = new HashMap<>();
    factories.put(Foo.class, new Factory<Foo>() {

      @Override
      public Foo fromInt(int i) {
        return Foo.fromInt(i);
      }

    });
    factories.put(Bar.class, new Factory<Bar>() {

      @Override
      public Bar fromInt(int i) {
        return Bar.fromInt(i);
      }

    });
    FACTORIES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(factories);
  }

  public static <T extends Enum<T>> T get(Class<T> type, int i) {
    Factory<T> factory = (Factory<T>) FACTORIES.get(type);
    if (factory != null) {
      return factory.fromInt(i);
    } else {
      throw new InvalidParameterException("No factory for type '" + type + "'");
    }
  }

}
```

As I always try to avoid reflection, I would personally choose the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that, but I would do it like this:

```
interface HasId() {
    public int getId();
}

public class MyRegistry {
    private static Map<Class<?>, Map<Integer, Object>> REGISTRY = new HashMap<>();
    public static <T extends HasId> T fromInt(int id, Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(REGISTRY.getOrDefault(clazz, Collections.emptyMap()).get(id));
    }
    public static void register(HasId obj) {
        REGISTRY.putIfAbsent(obj.getClass(), new HashMap<>()).put(obj.getId, obj);
    }
}

enum Foo implements HasId {
    A(15), B(42), C(86), D(99);
    private final int id;
    Foo(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        MyRegistry.register(this);
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
// ditto for other enums or non enums as you like
```

Then to use:

```
Foo foo = MyRegistry.fromInt(15, Foo.class); // A
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: Note that `putIfAbsent` doesn’t work the way you seem to expect (it’s not like `computeIfAbsent`). `putIfAbsent` always returns the old value, i.e. `null` if there was no previous mapping and the previous (still present) value otherwise. Further, it doesn’t help to use a thread safe map, when it’s contained non-threadsafe `Set` is accessed without any protection.

Comment: Also, the code relies on class initialization of the actual `enum` type which is not guaranteed. On the other hand, it would be easy to let `fromInt` iterate over the enum values reflectively, eliminating the need for the registration.

Comment: @Holger Isn't enum initialization guaranteed due to the class literal being passed in to the call?

Comment: No, a class literal alone is not sufficient. [The spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) does not list class literals as trigger. And it’s not a theoretical issue, I just verified that in Oracle’s JVM, class literals indeed won’t trigger an initialization…